# How can typeset \qty{4\pi e-7}{\henry\per\meter} in siunitx version v3.0.2

Tags: siunitx

In previous `siunitx` I was able to typeset permeability constant:

- `\SI{4\pi e-7}{\henry\per\meter}`

I just expect that it can be simple rewritten to

- `\gty{4\pi e-7}{\henry\per\meter}`

but Siunitx complains: ! Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '4\mitpi e-7'

What is the recommended solution?

Comment: Did you mean `\qty` instead of `\gty`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As (now) detailed in the manual, you can add `\pi` as a 'digit'

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-digits = 0123456789\pi}
\begin{document}

\SI{4\pi e-7}{\henry\per\meter}

\end{document}
```

If you are using `unicode-math`, you'll need to either add `\mipi` (the expansion of `\pi`) or make `\pi` itself robust.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginDocument{\robustify\pi}
\sisetup{input-digits = 0123456789\pi}
\begin{document}

\SI{4\pi e-7}{\henry\per\meter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution does not work when package "unicode-math" is used. Compiler is complaining: ! Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '4\mitpi e-7'.

Comment: @JardaFait See my edit