# siunitx valid number now invalid

Tags: siunitx, texlive-2021

The following works fine with TeXLive up through 2020:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num{\pi}
\end{document}
```

Starting with TeXLive 2021, this causes the error

```
! Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '\pi '.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 \num{\pi}
             

The input '\pi ' could not be parsed as a number following the format defined
in module documentation.
```

I understand that siunitx had a large change for 2021.  Is there a way to still have this compile?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597999/2388